# Copying std::vector: prefer assignment or std::copy?

Tags: c++, stl, copy

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;

// Filling v1
...
```

And now I need to copy `v1` to `v2`. Is there any reason to prefer

`v2 = v1;`

to

`std::copy (v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());`

(or vice versa)?

Comment: Assignment operator will do the right thing. The way you've written `copy`, it'll mess up if `v1` is larger than `v2`.

Comment: If `v1` is not required after the copy you could just `v2.swap(v1);`.

Comment: Write what you want to do. If you want to assign one vector to another, write that.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Generally I would strongly prefer `v2 = v1`:

1. It is shorter and makes the intent more clear
2. `std::copy` won't work if `v2` doesn't have the same length as `v1` (it won't resize it, so it will retain some of the old elements best case (`v2.size() > v1.size()` and overwrite some random data used elsewhere in the program worst case
3. If `v1` is about to expire (and you use C++11) you can easily modify it to `move` the contents
4. Performancewise assignment is unlikely to be slower then `std::copy`, since the implementers would probably use `std::copy` internally, if it gave a performance benefit.

In conclusion, `std::copy` is less expressive, might do the wrong thing and isn't even faster. So there isn't really any reason to use it here.

Comment: Then, what is `std::copy` for?

Comment: @altroware: It's for general copying from one range to another. You can't, for example, use the assignment operator to copy from a `std::list` to a `std::vector`, or from one portion of a `std::vector` to another portion of the same `std::vector`.

Comment: What will happen if v1 was allocated on the stack and gets destructed? Does `v2 = v1` cause elements of v1 to be copied?

Comment: Which copy mechanism of the element type is called? In this case of `vector<int>`, are the integers copied from one vector to the other with `operator=`, or with `int`'s copy constructor?

Comment: How would you implement operator=, in this case?

Comment: @james operator= Will do a full deep copy. Idiomatic C++ uses value semantics so copying a vector copies all its elements. The exception is if it’s elements are pointers in which case the pointers are copied. After assignment, the vectors are independent.

Answer (score 20):

If `v2` isn't big enough you'll get a buffer overrun if you use `copy` as you have.

You can use a back insert iterator which will call push_back on `v2`. However this could lead to multiple reallocations depending upon how big `v1` is.

```
copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), back_inserter(v2));
```

You're better off letting `vector` manage things correctly. The assignment operator does this, as does `vector::assign`:

```
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

I have an inkling that the assignment operator is implemented in terms of `vector::assign`.

Comment: Mr. Wood, is it possible that you meant v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end()) rather than v2.assign(v1.begin(), v2.end())?

Answer (score 13):

The invocation of `std::copy` may try to access items beyond the end of the destination vector.

Use assignment.

It's not your job to micro-optimize: that's the library writer's responsibility, and ultimately the compiler's responsibility.

You can make your code *arbitrarily fast* if it doesn't have to be correct.

In the case of the `copy`, however, it's rather doubtful whether it even is faster, and it's certainly not correct for the general case.

Comment: I agree with your statements concerning optimization, but it might be worth pointing out that the more information available to the compiler or the library, the better it can do its job.  Member functions of `std::vector` know that they're working on an `std::vector`, and know how it is implemented.  `std::copy` doesn't have this information.  The conclusion is that the member functions can probably do the job better (and certainly not worse).

Answer (score 2):

It's shorter.

`std::copy` is mainly meant for copying sections of containers. If you need to copy an entire container, you might as well use the copy constructor.

Comment: If `v2` isn't big enough you'll get a buffer overrun.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment, by far.  More generally, any time the size of the vector might change, or change the entire contents of the vector, you should prefer member functions.  The only time `std::copy` would be appropriate is if you are only replacing a small range totally within the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Assignement is clearer and internally uses `std::copy` (or `unitizalized_copy` `_M_allocate_and_copy` depending size and capacity) or  so performances are the same.