# vector erase multiple regions, 2 x erase vs single assign?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to erase 2 ranges of elements from vector, the vector looks like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

for example I need to keep only numbers 3 and 4. (in reality this could be big objects)

There are 2 options:

1) take target elements and drop the rest:

```
vec.assign(vec.begin() + 3, vec.begin() + 5);
```

2) explicitly remove ranges:

```
vec.erase(vec.begin() + 6, vec.end()); // first end (it's cheap)
vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 3); // then beginning (reallocates elements)
```

Which one of these 2 options will perform faster?

Or is there even better way?

Comment: The `vec.assign` version is undefined behavior because the iterators refer into what you're assigning to.  So the second option is better.

Comment: Worth seeing if `vec = std::vector<int>(vec.begin() + 3, vec.begin() + 5);` is a good solution.

Comment: Can you guarantee they are sorted (with no additional work)? Otherwise, I was going to say use partition with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom (and that might still be just as good)

Comment: @KennyOstrom in most cases yes, vectors need to be sorted, but not always. why? doing additional work to perform sort is not problem in my case. because I need to sort them sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) followed by [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). It's correct and likely uses `memcpy` or `memmove` for POD types so it should be fast. Something like:

```
auto itr = std::copy(vec.begin() + 3, vec.begin() + 5, vec.begin());
vec.erase(itr, vec.end());
```

If the vector elements are movable you could use the [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm instead of `std::copy`.

Comment: interesting, but, if I copy (or move) range to beginning of same vector, then the rest of elements will be reallocated anyway, prior to removal? itsn't this the same as my 2nd option which also reallocates in second `erase`

Comment: @metablaster No, the only elements that move are the copied range. The unwanted elements at the start of the vector are overwritten. There's no reallocation or extra data movement. The single (cheap) `erase` leaves only the desired values in the vector.

Comment: thanks! I find this solution the most effective! verified you comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977632/copying-stdvector-prefer-assignment-or-stdcopy oh, and happy new year btw.!